# How do I get Nginx https_upload module to save files by their names instead of an incrementing number?

Tags: c, file, http, nginx, https

I am using nginx with "http_upload_module"(https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/).

I want to save files from incoming requests in a certain directory by their name.
I have these directives in my nginx.conf :

```
 location /upload {
            # Pass altered request body to this location
            upload_pass /test;

            # Store files to this directory
            upload_store /usr/upload/path;

            # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
            upload_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;

            # Set specified fields in request body
            upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
            upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
            upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

            # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
            upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
            upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";

            upload_pass_form_field "^submit$|^description$";

            upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
        }

        # Pass altered request body to a backend
        location /test {
            add_header Content-Type "text/plain;charset=utf-8";
            return 200 "Upload succeeded";
        }
```

However, when I send a post message of a file using curl like so:
 `curl nginxIp/upload -F "fileobj=@$(pwd)/README.md" -F "name=readme.md"`
A file is saved to the defined directory, however its name is 00000001 (/usr/upload/path/0000001), and when I upload more files their names increment as well.

I would like to save the files to the directory by their names.

How can I do that?